# Fields with respect to the operations of addition modulo $m$ and multiplication modulo $m$:

Tags: discrete-mathematics, field-theory, integers

If $I_m$ denotes the set of integers modulo $m$, then the following are fields with respect to the operations of addition modulo $m$ and multiplication modulo $m$:

$(i) Z_{23}$

$(ii) Z_{29}$

$(iii) Z_{31}$

$(iv) Z_{33}$

---

My attempt:

Answers is given $(i), (ii),\space\text{and}\space(iii)$.

I have read upto group from Rosen. Sorry, I did not read field that was out of syllabus. This question was from UGC-NET-2004-ii-CS paper.

> Can you explain it, please?

Comment: With the modulo operations, $\;\Bbb Z_m\;$ is a field if and only if $\;m\;$ is a prime. And I'm afraid you'll have to read your book/notes to fully understnd this.

Comment: @DonAntonio, sorry, I should revise it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, a [field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)) is a thing where you can add, subtract, multiply and divide. It is a bit tricky to see that the first three examples ($\mathbb{Z}_{23}$, $\mathbb{Z}_{29}$, $\mathbb{Z}_{31}$) are indeed fields. In fact, $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ happens to be a field always when $p$ is prime, and this result follows from [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).

But let us look at the fourth example. Assume you can divide the elements by $11$, then you have $$3=\frac{11}{11}\cdot3=\frac{11\cdot3}{11}=\frac{33}{11}=0,$$ a contradiction. (The latter equality holds because $33=0$ modulo $33$.) A similar argument shows you that $\mathbb{Z}_q$ cannot be a field if $q$ is any composite number.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.